# The SELECT command in brackets is working for showing rows, how to update the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
UPDATE tab4mail SET emid = 'X' WHERE
(

SELECT tab1.colum1, tab1.colum2, tab1.status, tab2.idnr, tab2.role, tab3.colum2, tab4mail.emid

FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.colum1 = tab2.column9

JOIN tab3 ON (tab1.colum1 = tab3.colum1 and tab1.colum2 = tab3.colum2)

JOIN tab4mail ON tab2.idnr = tab4mail.idnr

WHERE tab1.status = 'X' and tab2.role = 'S'

);
```

The SELECT command in brackets is working for showing rows.

Now I want to update the table "tab2mail" and want to SET as "X". I'm not sure where to write/add this UPDATE. In first line or somewhere else? I only want to replace in "tab4mail" these rows which fulfil the conditions of SELECT command, written in brackets.

Comment: Can you more clearly describe your update logic?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an `IN` clause.

```
UPDATE tab4mail 
SET emid = 'X' 
WHERE idnr IN (
        SELECT tab4mail.idnr 
        FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.colum1 = tab2.column9
        JOIN tab3 ON (tab1.colum1 = tab3.colum1 and tab1.colum2 = tab3.colum2)
        JOIN tab4mail ON tab2.idnr = tab4mail.idnr
        WHERE tab1.status = 'X' and tab2.role = 'S'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, This one worked fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tab4mail
    SET emid = 'X'
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tab1 JOIN
                       tab2
                       ON tab1.colum1 = tab2.column9 JOIN
                       tab3
                       ON tab1.colum1 = tab3.colum1 and tab1.colum2 = tab3.colum2
                  WHERE tab2.idnr = tab4mail.idnr AND tab1.status = 'X' and tab2.role = 'S'
                 );
```

Comment: For what you written SELECT 1 in bracket, i mean what does that mean & is EXIST what i need, if i only want to update these rows which matches the Select criteria, i cant just try the command, because I'm worry if it updates all the rows in emid of table tab4mail.

Comment: your query changed all 24K records instead of only 5k.

Comment: This query is wrong.  It'll update ALL records if ANY of them match the criteria.  You need to key them like above.

Comment: @ChrisAllwein . . . I don't see why you say that.  Do you understand how a correlated subquery works?